# Handle Ajax call on server side and response back to the page that made the ajax call

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am sending some data to a webpage  by ajax call in `javascript`. I have successfully done this. Now what i want is to do some programming on the server  side like get the data and storing the data in database and send the response may be some weburl link etc to a page from where the ajax call is sent.

My code on client page is given below:

**page1.aspx**

```
 $.ajax({
        url: "www.abc.com/Page2.aspx?weburl=" + something+ "&ip_click=" + something+ "&src=" + source,
        type: "GET",
        complete: function (data) {

        }
```

now i got this parameters on page2.aspx. Now how can i send response back from page2.aspx to page1.aspx.
please help how can i achieve this?
Thanks

Comment: what response you want to send back?

Comment: you are simply redirecting from one page to another. why you are using ajax call here?

Comment: it can be some weburl link like www.abc.com/abc.aspx..

Comment: it is because both the pages are in different domains and i need to send some data like IP address and  current user info to the other by ajax call in  javascript(as i cannot use server side language here)

Comment: If you are using ajax call on same page then you can simply send back a response. But not sure about different pages. I think your code is working like a simple redirect...

Comment: i do not want to open the page2.aspx page..Page1.aspx will just send data to page2.aspx through ajax and which will be handled by the page2.aspx. now page2 want to send some response to page1.aspx .how can i send that from page2.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly send data from ajax call to another page. This data will be available on the page that send that call in response callback(onComplete). So if you load Page1.aspx which contains ajax call to Page2.aspx, results will arrive on Page1.aspx (which is currently loaded in browser), not Page2 and anything else. Sever can't send data on non-existing page (o.c. it can do http-request to that page with that params, but it's very bad way).

So i.e. if you have homepage Home.aspx which do ajax call to Page2:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "www.abc.com/Page2.aspx?weburl=" + something+ "&ip_click=" + something+ "&src=" + source,
        type: "GET",
        complete: function (data) {

        }
});
```

And that data is needed on Page1 you should do another call (possibly POST):

```
$.ajax({
        url: "www.abc.com/Page2.aspx?weburl=" + something+ "&ip_click=" + something+ "&src=" + source,
        type: "GET",
        complete: function (data) {
             $.post("http://www.abc.com/Page1.aspx", data, function(result){});
        }
});
```

Comment: i got it.but i want to send response from the page2 which is getting data from the page1,saves that data  and then will  finally send some response (let say:"record is saved" or if it is not it should "sorry already have the same id") .that response i want to show in the alert box in page1. Now how can i send response back to page1.?as now i have saved the data but do not know how to send back the response .right now getting just (object object) in the alert box on page1.

Comment: You're on home page, not page1 or page2. All responses go to home page. You can access only to page that you're currently viewing. And show alert only on home page.